# How to use ForeignKey field in Django Model

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I am using this in my Model

```
bank  = models.ForeignKey(Bank)
```

But in my editable form I have the select box but the values which appear is like

`Bank object`

Is there any option so I can see field like `Bank.name` in select box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By overriding the `__unicode__` method of your `Bank` class, you can provide alternative display values for your model instances.

```
class Bank(models.Model):

    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

define a **unicode** method for Bank class like below:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the Choicefield, try this link:

- http://www.viksit.com/node/16